# How to plot using matplotlib (python) colah's deformed grid?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, grid, distortion

I need to create a visualization in Python just like colah's did on his site. However, I could not find any distortion to grid on matplotlib to perform exactly like he did [here](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-03-NN-Manifolds-Topology/). Pls, help me if you can.

This is the plot I need to perform:
[image: colah's vector field space distortion]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would guess the image is produced by adding some gaussian function to the grid.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

def plot_grid(x,y, ax=None, **kwargs):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    segs1 = np.stack((x,y), axis=2)
    segs2 = segs1.transpose(1,0,2)
    ax.add_collection(LineCollection(segs1, **kwargs))
    ax.add_collection(LineCollection(segs2, **kwargs))
    ax.autoscale()


f = lambda x,y : ( x+0.8*np.exp(-x**2-y**2),y )

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

grid_x,grid_y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3,3,20),np.linspace(-3,3,20))
plot_grid(grid_x,grid_y, ax=ax,  color="lightgrey")

distx, disty = f(grid_x,grid_y)
plot_grid(distx, disty, ax=ax, color="C0")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly what I was looking for!