# How to plot a 2d structured mesh in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mesh

I am trying to use matplotlib to plot the structured mesh (See the figure below)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1, 11), np.linspace(0, 0.6, 7))

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I got a discrete points, but I have no idea how to connect them to get something like this:

The desired result is:

[image: The desired result in this link]

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd use two linecollections for this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1, 11), np.linspace(0, 0.6, 7))

plt.scatter(x, y)

segs1 = np.stack((x,y), axis=2)
segs2 = segs1.transpose(1,0,2)
plt.gca().add_collection(LineCollection(segs1))
plt.gca().add_collection(LineCollection(segs2))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Also see [How to plot using matplotlib (python) colah's deformed grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295473/how-to-plot-using-matplotlib-python-colahs-deformed-grid)

Because if the grid is not deformed, it would be more efficient to draw a single linecollection, like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1, 11), np.linspace(0, 0.6, 7))

segs1 = np.stack((x[:,[0,-1]],y[:,[0,-1]]), axis=2)
segs2 = np.stack((x[[0,-1],:].T,y[[0,-1],:].T), axis=2)

plt.gca().add_collection(LineCollection(np.concatenate((segs1, segs2))))
plt.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This will work also if the grid is not a rectangle (For example, grid around a circle).

Answer (score 12):

You can `np.transpose` the points you already have, while using a line `plot()` rather than `scatter()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1, 11), np.linspace(0, 0.6, 7))

plt.plot(x, y) # use plot, not scatter
plt.plot(np.transpose(x), np.transpose(y)) # add this here
plt.show()
```

You can of course have it colored in **black** with `c='k'`
[image]

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, `vlines` and `hlines` would do:

```
plt.vlines(np.linspace(0,1,11), 0, 0.6)
plt.hlines(np.linspace(0,0.6,7), 0, 1)
```

If you already have mesh `x,y`:

```
plt.vlines(x[0], *y[[0,-1],0])
plt.hlines(y[:,0], *x[0, [0,-1]])
```

Out:

[image]